# global variable is not updated inside function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the following Code

```
var base64 = ''
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
let awsConfig = {
  'region': 'us-west-2',
  'endpoint': 'http://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  'accessKeyId': 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMANOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
  'secretAccessKey': 'ABCDABSDJFGJALGJADSLGJALKDJGALKSDJGLA'
}

AWS.config.update(awsConfig)

let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

let fetchOneByKey = function () {
  var params = {
    TableName: 'test',
    Key: {
      'key1': 'abc'
    }
  }
  docClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('test::fetchOneByKey::error - ' + err)
    } else {
      base64 = data.Item.b.toString('base64')
    }
  })
}

fetchOneByKey()
console.log(base64)
```

For some reason my variable `base64` prints nothing. This is weird because when I do `console.log(data.Item.b.toString('base64')` it prints the `base64` string so i know the data is not empty for sure.

For some reason my variable is not getting updated and I am not sure why. I am clearly calling the function `fetchOneByKey()` so in theory `base64` should get updated but it is not.

Comment: You're attempting to log the `base64` variable before the callback for `docClient.get()` runs.

Comment: Your `console.log` is outside the callback of where `base64` is assigned.

Comment: The variable is updated, but you're reading the value before the update happens.

Comment: @TylerRoper How do i ensure the update happens so my var gets updated?

Comment: Anything that relies on the result of your `docClient.get()` should be initiated within the callback or after `await`ing the result.

Comment: @TylerRoper i would love to see example if you can post ,

Comment: Was just about to flag the duplicate as it was closed with the same one. The linked question should provide some insight.

Comment: Either you will have to use promise or callback. follow [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/bdc7r3m5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docClient.get()` is asynchronous. By calling `console.log()` immediately after calling the function, you are executing it before the read from DB is finished, and thus your variable isn't updated.

Call `console.log(base64)` here

```
else {
  base64 = data.Item.b.toString('base64')
  console.log(base64)
}
```

If you want to get rid of the callback and use promises instead, you can use [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html). With that you can turn it into a promise and use it with `async/await` or chain it with `.then()`.

Or you can make it as promise manually.

```
let fetchOneByKey = function () {
  var params = {
    TableName: 'test',
    Key: {
      'key1': 'abc'
    }
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    docClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('test::fetchOneByKey::error - ' + err)
        reject(err)
      } else {
        base64 = data.Item.b.toString('base64')
        resolve(base64)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

then you can say `base64 = await fetchOneByKey();`
or if you are not inside an `async` function you can do `fetchOneByKey().then(base64 => console.log(base64))`

EDIT: 
as @AZ_ mentioned, `aws-sdk`supports promises

```
let fetchOneByKey = async function () {
  var params = {
    ...
  }
  const data = await docClient.get(params).promise();
  base64 = data.Item.b.toString('base64');
  return base64
}
```

Comment: yes i know that works but i want to use that variable outside the function.

Comment: @Dinero Use promisify and make that callback into a promise. Then you can use async/await or you can chain it with .then()

Comment: can you edit and show? i have never used that

Comment: I edited. Can you try it now?

Comment: `aws-sdk` already provides the promise wrapper. so no need a separate `new Promise...`.

Comment: @AZ_ that's even better. I'm not familiar with aws-sdk.

Comment: @AZ_ feel free to post yours as a answer too

Comment: already added the snippet in comments.